# Caching properties using Hikaricp in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, oracle11g, hikaricp

I need to know what are the connection caching properties, im using Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition and Express Edition, Hibernate and HikariCP.

I put these properties in my hibernate.cfg but i get an exception:

```
    <property name="hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts">true</property>
    <property name="hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize">250</property>
    <property name="hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</property>
    <property name="hikari.dataSource.useServerPrepStmts">true</property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those properties are MySQL properties; Oracle is different.  Try:

```
<property name="hikari.dataSource.implicitCachingEnabled">true</property>
<property name="hikari.dataSource.maxStatements">250</property>
```

See [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/stmtcach.htm#i1069942) for details.

Comment: In my case, those properties didn't work. I had to use dataSource.oracle.jdbc.implicitStatementCacheSize instead